# Can some one help what is the difference between window.showModalDialog and window.open in javascript

Tags: javascript

Can some one help what is the difference between `window.showModalDialog` and `window.open` in javascript. I have a website where `window.showModalDialog` stopped working in  Google Chrome. Also can some one tell what is the return value for the two methods

Tried `window.showModalDialog` in the JS code but it didn't worked. When I tried with `window.open()` it worked

Answer (score 1):

According to [`Window.showModalDialog`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showModalDialog), this method is deprecated and was removed in **Chrome 43** and **Firefox 56**. That's why it no longer work. So don't use this method.

For the return value part

- [`Window.showModalDialog()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showModalDialog#return_value):

> Holds the `returnValue` property as set by the document specified by uri.

- [`Window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#return_value):

> A `WindowProxy` object. The returned reference can be used to access properties and methods of the new window as long as it complies with the same-origin policy security requirements.

You should check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) for more information